# YTPlayerView work in simulator but not in Iphone Device in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code:

```
    @property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;
    [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE"];
```

I am working on playvideo from youtube..but this code it work in simulator perfectly but not in device.. any one have idea why this issue occur..

Comment: What is not working, do you get an error?

Comment: my video from youtube work in simulator but when i run in iphone device it gives no error but display only white screen..

Comment: Did you step through your code, is `loadWithVideoId` executed without issues?

Comment: yes i tried  loadWithVideoId execute without issues but no result of video

Comment: Make sure your device is connected with proper internet...If you have connected with wifi then make sure wifi has access for youtube video

Comment: your code is almost correct...try to check your IPhone OS if your operating system is 8.0 then it won't work..it's bug of IOS 8.0..For more info you can check [IOS 8.0 BUG](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1557471)

Answer (score 1):

Add `delegate` `YTPlayerViewDelegate` and `delegate` methods like

```
- (void)playerViewDidBecomeReady:(nonnull YTPlayerView *)playerView;
- (void)playerView:(nonnull YTPlayerView *)playerView receivedError:
- (YTPlayerError)error;
```

may be you can get your answer here.